# Error ! Missing } inserted

Tags: errors, arabtex

My tex file contains

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}


\begin{abstract}
Test
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
test .
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

It's give me the error

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.26 \end{abstract}
```

When I remove the abstract block the error is solved but doesn't make sense.
and also when I remove the using package "arabtex" and "utf8" the error also solved but my actual paper use those packages.

How to solve this problem, Thanks in advance

Comment: I simplified your example,m narrowing the problem down to a clash between arabtex and elsarticle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `arabtex` package redefines `\endabstract` to do `\endlist` instead of `\egroup` (which is what `elsarticle` expects).

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{arabtex}

% fix the redefinition of \endabstract done by arabtex
\def\endabstract{\egroup}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}


\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{abstract}
Test
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
test .
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

The problem is in line 297 of `asect.sty` that has

```
\let \endabstract \endquotation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's worked finally. I'm in this point about month